# PDO : creating a reusable code

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a reusable code in PDO.

here's my code.

```
$myClass = new main_c();
$condition = "email_address = :email_address AND password = :password";
$array = array('email_address' => 'yiihii@yahoo.com', 'password' => '98467a817e2ff8c8377c1bf085da7138');
$row = $myClass->get('user', $condition, $array, $db);
print_r($row);
```

Here's my function.

```
      public function get($tablename, $condition, $array, $db){

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE $condition");
        foreach($array as $k=>$v){

            $stmt->bindParam(":$k", $v);
        }

        try{
            $stmt->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            $error = new main_c();
            echo $error->error_handling($e);
        }

        return $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
```

I've tried omitting the `AND` in the condition and just put a single where clause and it worked. I think there's a problem in the foreach. i'm not sure though.

Comment: Any errors? What final query you get? I would omit `$db` parameter as it should be some variable created on initialization. Include type hints fro attributes

Comment: @Justinas no errors so far.. sir jeroen is correct need to change the bindParam to bindValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not binding values, but parameters, so in your loop you are only binding one variable `$v` to key `$k`. Twice. And by the time you execute your query these variables will contain the values of the last iteration of the loop.

You would need to change [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) to [`bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).

However, as you are not using the third parameter of `bindParam()` / `bindValue()` - forcing a data type - you can skip that whole loop and do:

```
try {
  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE $condition");
  $stmt->execute($array);
  ...
```